# what happens to database connection created by rake task while loading rails environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rake-task

A rake task loads application environment each time when it runs and therefore creates database connection, what happens to these connections after its execution is over? Please explain and suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same thing that happens when you shutdown the `rails server` and `rails console` etc. They get disconnected.

Comment: please can you provide me with authoritative reference, if possible.